# MATLAB - autocorrelation of a huge amount of values

Tags: matlab

I have a *txt* file containing a huge amount of values (~4 millions values, one for each line of the above mentioned *txt* file) and I would like to use the MATLAB function [`autocorr`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html) in order to calculate the autocorrelation of the above mentioned series of values.

My problem is that MATLAB does not allow me to create a vector that has as many elements as I need but instead the vector size is limited to something like ~25000 elements (on a 64bit OS).

What would be a clever way to proceed? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don' think there should be a problem generating a vector of 4 million entries in any of todays pcs. `double` values require 64 bits or 8 bytes, so you'd roughly need 8*4 = 24 MB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is probably breaking file data into chunks, computing the autocorrelation for each chunk and then aggregate the results.

Expanding a little on this, you could also use moving windows instead of discrete chunks (for example: observations 1-30, then 2-31, then 3-32, ...).

But let's stick on the first approach for the moment. Here is a function that allows you to specify a block length and then read the file blocks:

```
function res = readFileChunks(file,chunkSize)
    fid = fopen(file,'r');

    if (fid < 0)
        error('Cannot open file "%s".',file);
    end

    res = {};

    while (~feof(fid))
        res{end+1} = fscanf(fid,'%f',[1 chunkSize])';
    end

    fclose(fid);
end
```

Example:

```
res = readFileChunks('data.txt',2500);
```

Now, all you have to do is sanitize your result (clearing, for example, empty cells caused by empty file lines) and process your autocorrelation into a loop for each vector.

Since Matlab loops are quite expensive, you could also calculate your autocorrelation values directly into the loop that reads file chunks. This way you will directly receive the final result.